# Front view and side view

Tags: modeling, camera

Just wondering, is there a way to have a model change depending on the camera angle? For example, in front view, you can see Mickey Mouses ears typically on top his head. But on side view his years keep facing the camera as they would from the front view. Not sure if I'm asking the right question, but is there a way to have that Mickey Mouse ears effect thing depending on the angle? And also, is there a way to have the front and side view models to change seamlessly?